# Check the size of tkinter window using "if" statement

Tags: python, tkinter

I want an if-function to check the geometry of a window in python (tkinter).
This is what I've got, but it doesn't work:

```
 if root.geometry == "457x450":
    print("The window is 457x450 pixels!")

 else:
    print("The window is not 457x450!")

 

 root = Tk()
 root.geometry("300x300")

 root.mainloop()
```

In this case it should print "The window is not 457x450!"

Answer (score 3):

The condition `if root.geometry == "457x450":` will never be true. `root.geometry` is a bound method that you compare to a string. You will need to call it like `root.geometry()` to retrieve the geometry string from tkinter.

However a geometry string has the form of `widthxheight+x+y` So your condition will still not turn to `True` even you have the right `width` and `height`.

A simple way of doing it would be:
`if root.geometry().split('+')[0] == "457x450":`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `root.winfo_height()` and `root.winfo_width()` to query the current width and height of the window in pixels.

Note that if you call these methods immediately after starting your app (i.e., by calling `root.mainloop()`) you'll get erroneous numbers because the window size hasn't been established yet, so you should call `root.update_idletasks()` *before* the call(s) to the `winfo_` methods!

This should to what you want:

```
root.update_idletasks()  # make sure the window is up to date
width, height = root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()  # get the window dimensions

if (width, height) == (457, 450):
   print("The window is 457x450 pixels!")
else:
   print("The window is not 457x450!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I figured it out! I just have to store the actual size of the window in a variable....

```
root = Tk()
size = "304x450"
root.geometry(size)
root.mainloop()
```

and then just say..

```
if size == "457x450":
    print("Hello World")
```

Worked for me. I just had to globalize the variable if I'm using it in a function.